# How to code Online Offline User status without Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I am trying to show in my chat script whether user who sent message is online or offline.

For that, there is continuous 800milisecond ajax going on to fetch chat message from chat.txt file, but my problem is to show whether given user is online or offline status.

I have tried this :-

```
function show_status() {
    var id = ("#id").val();
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'/status.php?id='+id,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/html");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and in status.php ... i have this code :-

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
      if( $_GET['id'] === '123') {
         echo 'Online';
      } else {
         echo 'Offline';
      }
    }
    if( $_GET['id'] === '321') {
       echo 'Online';
    } else {
    echo 'Offline';
    }
?>
```

But problem is , If my id is 123 , it shows to me, my account as online and even if 321 is online it shows offline and for user with is 321, it shows his id 321 online and other account offline, is there any method, to overrule.. this and show all current user who are online as online. 
Without touching database, i don't want to run query every time in database.

Comment: and why not to use jquery? Why don't you use switch?

Comment: Each of you is being presented with your own unique DOM. On your DOM, your status is Online, his is not. On his DOM, his status is Online, yours is not. Without the use of a database or very large sessions, I'm not sure how you can accomplish this.

Comment: even with the session its not happening.. I am setting session `$_SESSION['online'] = 'online'` when $_GET['id'] is set and if it not than i am setting it offline.. and it still shows to self online and rest user offline :(

Comment: $_SESSION is user based and should NEVER be used to store data over multiple users. A $_SESSION is bound to a user and should always be that. What you could do is create a different file: status.txt where you keep the last_time_seen for every user. If it is more then 4 seconds he is offline.

Comment: there will be multiple instance of such chat, and i dont want to create status.txt file for each chat page/instance. :(